# Jquery Selector not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css-selectors

Internet Explorer does not like my Jquery selector. Not sure if it's my weak Jquery
skills or general Explorer strangeness.

Here is the Code:

```
$("#field_"+index+" #field_Label").val();
```

[div field_1]

```
<input id="field_Label" //... you get the picture.
```

to explain this.. I have a DIV labeled field_1, field_2.. etc.. 
Internet explorer appears to find the first iteration, but cannot
find the second.

Thank you all, and thanks to you stackoverflow.

Is there a better way I should be doing this ?..

Here is a more complete snippet:

```
<li id="blank">
<div  id="field_1" style="background: #BDCFFF; color: #1028BD;margin: 10px; border: 1px solid black;width: 400px; height: 100px;">
<table>
<tr><td>Label:</td><td><input class="field_Label" id="field_Label" type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Type:</td><td><input id="field_Type" type="text" value="2"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Id:</td><td><input id="idField" type="text" value="0"/></td></tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: You're not trying to use the same "id" value for more than one element, are you? Because that won't work; it kind-of goes against the definition of "id", which has to be globally unique on the page.

Comment: Why is this under community wiki?

Comment: Yeah.. I know its strange.. It worked on Safari and Firefox.. I'm not sure what is up.. I could switch to classes and ID's I guess..  What I am really trying to say is give me the label with THIS ID, in side of this DIV..

Comment: Pointy +1: as he pointed out *below* in some comment, "id" is scoped at the page level. You should not have more than one element with an id of #field_label on a page. Why not give the innermost/most specific elements some id  - you can then work your way either upwards to the parents, or sideways, to the siblings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change #field_Label to .field_Label and then access

```
$("#field_"+index+".field_Label").val();
```

Without a space beween the values, so the output would be #field_1.field_Label - (Ie likes specifics)

Comment: Strangely.. I tried that.. changed the label to a class.. and back
and forth.. still strange.

alert ($("#field_1.field_Label").val());

<input class="field_Label" id="field_Label" type="text"/>

Comment: I'm not sure if this is any help but you might want to drill down a bit, (#field_1, table, .field_label) or something, as tables can have funny effects on DOM structure in IE.

Either way, if you just added the class name as class='field_1_Label' etc, you'd be able to access them directly and shouldn't be any harder doing it that way

Answer (score 3):

Try using a class on the input instead of id. Only one input should have id field_Label.

```
<input class="field_Label" />
selector: $("#field_"+index+" .field_Label").val();
```

This is an update considering the code snippet you added. I rewrote it changing id to class.

```
<div  id="field_1">
<table>
<tr><td>Label:</td><td><input class="field_Label" type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Type:</td><td><input class="field_Type" type="text" value="2"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Id:</td><td><input class="idField" type="text" value="0"/></td></tr>
</table>
</div>

Selectors:
var label = $("#field_1 .field_Label").val();
var type = $("#field_1 .field_Type").val();
var id = $("#field_1 .idField").val();
```

Class instead of id if you are going to have many tables with same kind of input. Otherwise if the inputs are unique just use id, example:  selector: $("#idField").val()

Answer (score 2):

Separate each selector with a comma:

```
$("#field_" + index + ", #field_Label")...........
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's after. My suspicion is that he is under the impression that "id" values are scoped under parent elements. That is not true. (Your answer isn't wrong, of course, but I don't think it applies.)

Comment: @Pointy: not that sure either, but looking at his question this is what i could grasp. Thanks

Comment: well maybe it will be helpful to **somebody** at least :-)

Comment: @Pointy: and i hope that **somebody** is questioner himself :)

Comment: Yeah.. I was just trying to add commas.. didn't seem to have an effect.

Strangely this works perfectly on Safari and Firefox..

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for the help.. I did finally resolve this.. it was just strange since
it only seemed to cause a problem with Internet Explorer.. but this is what I did to
get it working.

```
$("#field_"+index).find("#field_Label").val();
```

/* Long live StackOverflow !! */

Answer (score 0):

you should give your div's a class and do

```
 var inputvals = $('.class_name').val();
```

then you can do what you want with them as a whole and you don't have to comma seperate a bunch of ids

Comment: I was trying to break them apart since I'm pushing each of them onto an object in a Forloop.. I was trying to avoid that.. but might have to end up using .each on all of them individualy.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks everyone for the help.. I did
>   finally resolve this.. it was just
>   strange since it only seemed to cause
>   a problem with Internet Explorer.. but
>   this is what I did to get it working.
>
> $("#field_"+index).find("#field_Label").val();
>
> /* Long live StackOverflow !! */

You saved me HOURS of time. Thank you!!! IE is the devil

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Thanks everyone for the help.. I did finally resolve this.. it was just
> ```
>
> strange since it only seemed to cause
>   a problem with Internet Explorer.. but
>   this is what I did to get it working.
>
> ```
> $("#field_"+index).find("#field_Label").val();
>
> /* Long live StackOverflow !! */
> ```

As others have stated, the innermost .find() is not necessary and overly redundant.

Essentially, IDs are the fasted method of selection with jQuery's Sizzle selector engine.  Using a unique ID, selection is the fastest method.  Descending an ID from another ID only adds unnecessary additional computation.  You most likely won't experience any performance slow-downs, but it's not a good habit to get into.

This is what you should be doing to access that element:

```
$("#field_label").val();
```

Source:
http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

Answer (score 0):

Well, beside the fact that field_Label should be a class and not an id in what I see of your sample; if you really need to have two descendent id selectors, you can use a find().

So, instead of:

```
$("#field_" + index + " #field_Label")
```

You can use this:

```
$("#field_" + index).find("#field_Label")
```

This works fine in IE.